# How to translate "On brigue le suffrage des electeurs."?

Tags: traduction

In [this interview](https://www.arte.tv/fr/videos/084743-010-A/philosophie/) at +- 4:59 the man says

> Lorsqu'on brigue le suffrage des électeurs, il vaut mieux se dire démocrate.

How does one say in english "On brigue le suffrage des electeurs"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about English and not about Fench.

Comment: By the way did you notice you can have English subtitles to the video? And this is Arte, the subtitles are usually reliable. I checked this one, it is OK.

Comment: HOW is it possible that this answer is closed when you have "How do you say “to hell with everything” in French?", "Façons d'exprimer « ça m'a touché »" or "Comment traduire « full of beans » : adjectif simple, syntagme ou locution ?". It really seems ridiculous to me how arbitrary those decisions are!

Comment: @SteffX You might not have noticed you are on **French** Language and we do not answer questions about English. There are two SE sites where people can ask questions about English, no reason to mix attributions. What is  ridiculous is (to use your word) is that if the OP had been just slightly more attentive they would have seen the subtitles on the video, no need to ask anyone.

Comment: @SteffX: People are welcome to ask if they don't know the meaning of something, but asking how to phrase a translation of something they seem to already understand is better suited for a site focused on English.

Comment: @Maroon — I understand what you said but consider the following: if an OP asks for the meaning of "briguer", the first answers would be to look in a dictionary or to have more context. Here, the OP gave the whole expression just because it is necessary for a good translation, and he gets slammed for that same reason? That doesn't seem fair